# Should multiple projects have multiple TFS workspaces?

Tags: version-control, tfs

We migrated from VSS to TFS about 6 months ago.  Our way of storing projects was that we grouped them by category (Windows App, Web App, Infopath, SQLScripts, deprecated).
Under the 'Windows App' workspace we might have 3 .NET projects. The 'Web App' might have 3, etc, etc.  VSS was used more just to store the code repository than any real functionality VSS might provide.

Windows App ($/Windows App/ workspace)
   -->App1
   -->App2
   -->App3

Web App ($/Web App/ workspace)
   -->App1
   -->App2
   -->App3

The question I have is would it be better to have 1 workspace for EACH project?  One of the reasons I think for 'yes' is that if I am working on multiple projects in the same workspace when I do things like check in pending changes it will show me ALL of the pending changes including other projects I might not be currently working in.

Web App/App1 ($/Web App/App1 workspace)
Web App/App2 ($/Web App/App2 workspace)
Web App/App3 ($/Web App/App3 workspace)

I guess I'm looking for a best practices response.

thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the project I'm working on we have several branches for different versions of our application, and I (personally) create a different workspace for each branch. Each branch is a 'project' in itself.

It's nice, because it localizes your pending changes to that workspace - so my pending changes for branch 1 don't show up when I'm working on branch 2.

**Edit:** I just read the last part of your answer - yeah, pending changes for each workspace is a really nice feature, and I'd consider it a best practice to do things this way.

Comment: Thanks, now I just have to sell it to folks :)

Comment: Someone's true could be my true with this question. It was mindblowing for me too. So i started to use like you now then :)