# TFS 2008 build summary showing changesets from other solutions - is this normal?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We have a build definition in TFS 2008 that builds one of our solutions on request (not using CI) and this works fine.

I navigate to the Build Explorer for this definition and double-click a completed build to view the summary.  In the summary I expand "Associated changesets" to examine the list of changesets that were committed between the previous build and this one.

On close inspection, it appears that TFS simply lists *all* changesets between the two builds regardless of whether they were part of the solution being built or not.

Is there something wrong with our configuration, or is this simply how TFS works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it shows all changesets that were checked into somewhere in the workspace associated with the build definition.  If you are seeing unrelated changesets, you might want to try narrowing your workspace for the build definition.

Comment: Thanks, that would explain the behaviour - maybe our repository isn't set up in the most useful way.  Previous devs here have simply lumped all projects and solutions under one workspace which doesn't seem to be very good practice according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806833/should-multiple-projects-have-multiple-tfs-workspaces